# Data not recognized inside the function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, eval

I wonder why my `data123` is not recognized inside the `allEffects(fit2, ...)` call below? Is there a fix to this?

My "R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)", windows 10 machine.

`Error object 'data123' not found`

```
library(effects)

m1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp + cyl, data = mtcars)


foo <- function(fit,...) {
   
   data123 <- eval(fit$call$data)
   
   fit2 <- lm(fit$call$formula, data = data123)
      
   allEffects(fit2, ...)   #### 'data123' not recognized HERE  
}   
#----------EXAMPLE OF USE:
foo(m1)

# Error during wrapup: object 'data123' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `allEffects` function is very picky about environments. You need to make sure the dataset you want to use is in the same environment as the formula you use for the model. Try

```
foo <- function(fit,...) {
  
  data123 <- eval(fit$call$data)
  formula123 <- eval(fit$call$formula)
  environment(formula123) <- environment()
  
  fit2 <- lm(formula123, data = data123)
  
  allEffects(fit2, ...) 
}   
foo(m1)
```

Here we explicitly extract the formula and reset it's environment to the function's body which is where `data123` is defined.